# Vue v-for doesn't update directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

SOLVED: 
My bad.The problem is in my code logic, the tempLatest array is always empty so the array that contains the card never been updated. btw, thank you for all your answers

I want to create a program that show a collection of card. That collection will be updated every 15 seconds. But here comes the problem, the v-for doesn't update directly when a new card added to the list but when the page is refreshed it shows the proper output.

here is my code

```
<PersonCard v-for="item in latest" v-bind:key="item.id" :attendeeName="item.name" :image="item.picture" :department="item.department"/>
```

```
data() {
        return {
            latest: [],
            imgArr: [],
            notReady: true,
        }
    }
```

```
created() {
        console.log(this.site, this.sinceTime)
        this.fetchRecognizedFace();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.fetchRecognizedFace, 15000);
    }
```

```
// update this.latest
for (var j = 0; j < tempLatest.length; j++) {
    this.latest.unshift(tempLatest[j]);
}
```

Comment: could be problem with scope. if fetchRecognizedFace uses this keyword you run into problems. maybe try this.fetchRecognizedFace.bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

use the vue forceUpdate method[ways to rerender component](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.forceUpdate();
```

after you update the latest variable, call this one

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```

Comment: Forcing the whole component to update is not the correct aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use version of vue as **1.0.28**
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.min.js

Comment: Why would downgrading to the last major version fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations with how arrays can be re-active in Vue (See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

With this in mind, when you do your update, do it like so:

```js
for (var j = 0; j < tempLatest.length; j++) {
    this.$set(this.latest, j, tempLatest[j]);
}
```

Note: I've not tested this with your code so you might need to play around a little as you're currently looping the temp list and the indexes might not match but `$set` is the way to go. You might also try:

```
this.$set(this, 'latest', tempLatest)
```

instead of looping each item.